# How to find the row number based on a set of SFC coordinates, in order to pull out the value from another column

Tags: r, dplyr, r-sf

I am new to geodetic data in R, so apologies if this is way off. I have got a dataset, with a column (geometry), which contains SFC points, and a second column (IntersectingPoints):

```
IntersectingPoints             geometry
<list>                      <POINT [°]>
<int [4,415]>      (144.9179 -45.59569)
<int [3,388]>     (5.740768 49.15625)
<int [6,214]>        (2.18701 52.80779)
<int [7,948]>       (3.108628 50.58135)
<int [2,298]>      (-96.77081 37.37828)
```

I would like to input an x and y value, in order to find the row number, which I can then use to pull out the same value from the IntersectingPoints column. The code I have wrote is:

```
x = 144.9179

y = 45.59569

point_ref=st_point(c(x,y))

which(pt$geometry == point_ref)
```

I was expecting this to output the first row, however this does not work, I think as the geometry is classed as a list.

The error I get is:

```
Error in which(pt$geometry == point_ref) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In which(pt$geometry == point_ref) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.sfc", "Ops.sfg") for "=="
2: In pt$geometry == point_ref :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

How I can output the row number?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the `==` operator works for the `sf` objects but I saw that `sf` has a dedicated [filter function](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sfnetworks/vignettes/sfn03_join_filter.html) which returns you matching rows.

You can use it as following

```r
library(sf)

pt1 = st_point(c(144.9179, -45.59569))
pt2 = st_point(c(5.740768, 49.15625))
pt3 = st_point(c(2.18701, 52.80779))


(sfc = st_sfc(pt1, pt2, pt3))
pt = st_sf(data.frame(
  IntersectingPoints=c("4,415","3,388","6,214"),
  geom=sfc))

pt

x <- 144.9179
y <- -45.59569

point_ref=st_point(c(x,y))

> st_filter(pt, point_ref)
# Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 144.9179 ymin: -45.59569 xmax: 144.9179 ymax: -45.59569
# CRS:           NA
#   IntersectingPoints                   geometry
# 1              4,415 POINT (144.9179 -45.59569)
```

I saw that the object returned doesn't have an index value but if you need it you could add an index column to retrieve the index from that.

```r
pt$idx <- seq(1:nrow(pt)) # add index column

> st_filter(pt, point_ref)$idx
# [1] 1
> st_filter(pt, pt2)$idx
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If that sign of y-coordinate of `point_ref` gets fixed and both `point_ref` and  `pt` share the same coordinate system (or both are without, which doesn't seem to be the case here), that equality test theoretically could work. But it will probably fail with your real dataset -- you don't see the exact precision of numbers from tibble printout but the number of digits defined by the `digits` option. Checking floats for equality (with `==` ) is rarely worth it.

Though you could find which point is closest to the ref point or which is within a certain distance.

Those point seem to be all over the place, by default sf uses s2 for spehrical geometry when dealing with unprojected (lon/lat) coordinates and you might need to experiment with distances if you decide to go with `st_is_within_distance()` . https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf7.html .

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# example data 
pt <- readr::read_csv("x,y
                       144.9179,-45.59569
                       5.740768,49.15625
                       2.18701,52.80779
                       3.108628,50.58135
                       -96.77081,37.37828") |> 
  st_as_sf(coords =c("x", "y"), crs = "WGS84")

x = 144.9179
y = -45.59569

# to compare features, they need to have the same projection (crs)
point_ref=st_point(c(x,y)) |> st_sfc(crs = st_crs(pt))

# works with toy data but likely fails on actual dataset -- 
# it's just the printout that is limited to 7 digits (R default) 
# and real precision is something else.
which(pt$geometry == point_ref)
#> [1] 1

### more practical alternatives:
# find index of the closest point
which.min(st_distance(point_ref, pt))
#> [1] 1

# find points that are within 1m distance from point_ref
lengths(st_is_within_distance(pt, point_ref,  dist = units::set_units(1,m))) > 0
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>